# How can I make OS X Finder ICON VIEW act responsive?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

Finder is great for the icon view but the icon view doesn't adjust the icon layout when you alter the window dimensions... can we change this to act responsive??  Like Pinterest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Window you need to change, then

View Menu > Arrange By > Name [or any other sort option]

It will then live update.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!! Thanks SO MUCH... my head feels better now lol

Answer (score 1):

I find the Arrange views to be a little confusing now.  I prefer the old-fashioned Sorting, but it's not as obvious how to do this now.

Press Command-J (or View -> Show View Options) to bring up the options dialog and set a sort option (like by Name or Kind).

Basically, you need to have Arrange and/or Sort turned on to get the live rearrangement of icons as you resize windows.

Comment: Answer is also good... other guy got it first... thanks so much tho.